# Round table seating with two sitting next to each other probability question?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[This problem is asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616764/round-table-seating-probability-question) but I have another approach. Let me first restate the problem:

> N people(including A and B) sitting around a round table. What is the
> probability that A and B sitting next to each other

I imagine that we could "chain" A and B together so that we have $N - 1$ people only, so this problem turns into arranging $(N - 1)$ people around a round table and the result, as figured out in the link above, should be $$2!\frac{(N - 1)!}{N-1} / (N-1)! = \frac{2}{(N - 1)}$$. But this "has flaws" since as we permute A and B(I mean that's why we have $2!$ in the formula), we can also permute the other people. So, isn't the result doubled ?  The answer should be:
$$\frac{1}{N - 1}$$. (What I means by "doubled"):

[image]

Comment: You have to take care...if $N=2$ the answer is $1$, not $\frac 21$.  But, so long as $N>2$, $A$ has two seats next to them so the answer is $\frac 2{N-1}$.

Comment: How come I'm getting $\frac{2!(N - 1)!}{N!} = \frac{2!}{N}$??

Comment: Just something I notice is that the drawing you provide actually isn't the same formation around the table. It is the opposite. In the first drawing, 5 is to the left of 4 and in the second drawing 5 is to the right of 4. Just because everyone is sitting next to the same person as before doesn't make the two formations the same.

Comment: @nezamjazayeri That's a careless mistake of mine. Lol. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since *probability* has been asked for,  we can assume  numbered seats for simplicity, and either use combinations or permutations, eg using permutations, with $N>2$,

$Pr = \Large\frac{2N}{N\cdot(N-1)} = \Large\frac{2}{N-1}$

or using combinations, $Pr =\Large\frac{N}{\binom{N}2} = \Large\frac{2}{N-1}$

Needless to say, for $N = 2, Pr=1$

Answer (score 1):

Seat $A$.  It does not matter where since only the relative order matters in a circular permutation.

**Case 1:**  If $N = 2$, then $B$ must sit next to $A$, so the probability that $A$ and $B$ sit next to each other is $1$.

**Case 2:**  If $N > 2$, then there are $N - 1$ places where $B$ could sit, of which $2$ are adjacent to $A$.  Hence, for $N > 2$, the probability that $A$ and $B$ are adjacent is
$$\frac{2}{N - 1}$$
If you insist on using permutations, observe that relative to $A$, there are $(N - 1)!$ ways to seat the other $N - 1$ people.  There are two ways to seat $B$ next to $A$ and $(N - 2)!$ ways to seat the remaining $N - 2$ people.  Hence, the probability that $A$ and $B$ sit next to each other is
$$\frac{2(N - 2)!}{(N - 1)!} = \frac{2(N - 2)!}{(N - 1)(N - 2)!} = \frac{2}{N - 1}$$
which agrees with the result we obtained above.